# How to upload file on Django REST endpoint quickly?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, file-upload

I am using Django REST framework to upload a large csv file and extract the data from the file and save the data in the data. By large  file I mean file of like 10 to 50mb but when I upload a file its taking way longer then expected like 10 to 15mins but the endpoint keeps on processing and does not returns the response here is how my views.py looks like:

```
    from asyncore import read
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.parsers import  MultiPartParser, FormParser
from rest_framework.response import Response
import pandas as pd
from .models import ExtractedData
from .urls import urlpatterns
from django.urls import path
# Create your views here.


class FileUploadView(APIView):
    parser_classes = ( MultiPartParser, FormParser)
    def put(self, request, format=None):
        file_obj = request.FILES['file']
        df = pd.read_csv(file_obj)
        dict_data = df.to_dict(orient='records')
        for dict in dict_data:
            ExtractedData.objects.get_or_create(data=dict)        
       
        return Response({'details':"File Saved Succesfully"},  status=204)
```

Comment: you are processing a whole file here in your view and after that try to check if file not exists on your database create, checking that field maybe is heavy and takes a lot of time you can create some unique key for each file and then check if not exists create that. also I recommend to use celery and do this (reading file and save to database) as a background job not in your view to keep your HTTP connection live to processing this job It may also got timeout some times.

Comment: @mujad thanks for commenting, yeah after some searching on the web I found out this can be done using celery task